# Change reducer sorting order

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have the following output from my reducer

```
    Key            Value
1 1998-01-05         45
10 1998-01-09        20
2 1998-01-06         68
3 1998-01-07         85
4 1998-01-08         85
```

Lexicographically this is correct but I want it to sorted in Natural order e.g.

```
  Key              Value
1 1998-01-05         45
2 1998-01-06         68
3 1998-01-07         85
4 1998-01-08         85
10 1998-01-09        20
```

I wrote a KeyComparator to achieve this and below is the code but even this did not work out.

```
public static class KeyComparator extends WritableComparator {
            protected KeyComparator() {
                    super(IntWritable.class, true);
            }

            @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
            public int compare(WritableComparable w1, WritableComparable w2) {
                    IntWritable t1 = (IntWritable) w1;
                    IntWritable t2 = (IntWritable) w2;
                    String t1Items = t1.toString();
                    String t2Items = t2.toString();
                    return t1Items.compareTo(t2Items);
            }
    }
```

Note my mapper output have the same format as the reducer but reducer is just outputting the maximum value.

What am I missing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are comparing Strings instead of comparing values.  "10" < "2" even though `10` > `2`.

You need to get the first field from your IntWritable or parse the first number and compare it.

BTW: If you are going to use `toString()`, you don't need to cast it first as all `Object` support this method.

Comment: Its sorts in the right order now but it drops other keys starting with the same integer. e.g 1 1998-01-05  45, 1 1998-01-05  46; it drops the first and keep the second. Do you know what might cause this?

Comment: If you are using a SortedMap or SortedSet, these will ignore duplicates.  The solution is to use a List and sort that with Collections.sort().

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing strings

```
               String t1Items = t1.toString();
               String t2Items = t2.toString();
               return t1Items.compareTo(t2Items);
```

You should not do this. Compare the numbers instead. I have no idea what `IntWritable` is but you should not create string from it. Extract integers and compare them directly.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way is the trivial way in this case:

```
public int compare(WritableComparable w1, WritableComparable w2) {
  return w1.compareTo(w2);
}
```

`IntWritable` already implements the `Comparable` interface the proper way.

That said, you may not even need your custom comparator class.

Comment: This will give me the Lexicographically ordering which is not what I want.

Comment: Then you have a different kind of error in your code. An `IntWritable` definitely does not sort lexicographically. It doesn't even hold a string representation, but a primitive `int`. My code is **equivalent to yours** (except for not sorting lexicographically).